# Haskell Function for checking if element is in Tree, returning Depth

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am currently doing an assigment for a class in which I have to implement a function which checks if an element is in a tree.

It is supposed to return `Nothing` when the element is not in the tree and `Just` (depth at which it was found) when it is.

An example:

```
sample1  
##1
#3 2
###7 5   6 4

 - contains 6 sample1 returns Just 2 
 - contains 1 sample1 returns Just 0  
 - contains 2 sample1 returns Just 1 
 - contains 8 sample1 returns Nothing
```

Here is what we are given:

Heap functional data structure:

```
module Fdata.Heap where

-- A signature for min-heaps
data Heap e t = Heap {
  empty :: t e,
  insert :: e -> t e -> t e,
  findMin :: t e -> Maybe e,
  deleteMin :: t e -> Maybe (t e),
  merge :: t e -> t e -> t e,
  contains :: e -> t e -> Maybe Int
}
```

An implementation of self-adjusting heaps:

```
import Fdata.Heap
import Fdata.Tree

-- An implementation of self-adjusting heaps
heap :: (Eq e, Ord e) => Heap e Tree
heap = Heap {
  empty = Empty,
  insert = \x t -> merge' (Node x Empty Empty) t,
  findMin = \t -> case t of
    Empty -> Nothing
    (Node x _ _) -> Just x,
  deleteMin = \t -> case t of
    Empty -> Nothing
    (Node _ l r) -> Just (merge' r l), 
  merge = \l r -> case (l, r) of
    (Empty, t) -> t
    (t, Empty) -> t
    (t1@(Node x1 l1 r1), t2@(Node x2 l2 r2)) ->
      if x1 <= x2
        then Node x1 (merge' t2 r1) l1
        else Node x2 (merge' t1 r2) l2,
  contains = \x t -> case (x,t) of 
    (x,Empty)-> Nothing
    (x,tx@(Node x1 l1 r1) -> 
      |x==x1 = Just 0 
      |x>x1  = (1+ (contains x l)
      |x<x1  = (1+ (contains x r)


}
    where 
        merge' = merge heap
```

The tree implementation

```
module Fdata.Tree where

import Fdata.Heap

data Tree x
  = Empty
  | Node x (Tree x) (Tree x)
    deriving (Eq, Show)

leaf x = Node x Empty Empty

-- Convert a list to a heap
list2heap :: Heap x t -> [x] -> t x
list2heap i = foldl f z
  where
    f = flip $ insert i
    z = empty i

-- Convert a heap to a list
heap2list :: Heap x t -> t x -> [x]
heap2list i t
  = case (findMin i t, deleteMin i t) of
      (Nothing, Nothing) -> []
      (Just x, Just t') -> x : heap2list i t'
```

I am supposed to implement the `contains` function in the implementation for self-adjusting heaps.

I am *not* allowed to use any helper functions and I am supposed to use the `maybe` function.

My current implementation:

```
contains = \x t -> case (x,t) of 
(x,Empty) -> Nothing
(x,tx@(Node x1 l1 r1))  
    |x==x1 -> Just 0 
    |x>x1  -> (1+ (contains x l1)
    |x<x1  -> (1+ (contains x r1)
```

This does not work, since I get a parse error on input `|`. 
I really dont know how to fix this since I did use 4 spaces instead of tabs and according to this: https://wiki.haskell.org/Case
the syntax is correct...

I once managed to fix this, but I got a type error about `(1+ (contains x l)`, so this probably is not correct.

Any hint would be appreciated.

EDIT: 
Thanks to everyone who answered!
Really appreciate that everyone took the time to explain their answers in great detail.

First of all: 
there were some smaller mistakes, as pointed out by some of you in the comments:

I missed one closing parenthesis and accidentially named one argument `l1` and another `r1` and afterwards used `r` and `l`. 
Fixed both mistakes.

Someone wrote that I do not need to use a lambda function. The problem is when I use something like:

```
contains _ Empty = Nothing
```

I get the error:

> parse Error on input '_'.

However, lambda functions do not give me any errors about the input arguments.

Currently the only function that works without any errors is:

```
contains = \e t -> case (e,t) of
(_,Empty) -> Nothing
(e , Node x t1 t2) ->
    if e == (head (heap2list heap (Node x t1 t2)))
        then Just 0
        else if (fmap (+1) (contains heap e t1))== Nothing
                    then (fmap (+1) (contains heap e t2))
                    else (fmap (+1) (contains heap e t1))
```

Found at:
[Counting/Getting "Level" of a hierarchical data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44797426/counting-getting-level-of-a-hierarchical-data)

Found by:Krom

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting/Getting "Level" of a hierarchical data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44797426/counting-getting-level-of-a-hierarchical-data)

Comment: Maybe you made a mistake when copying your code, but your parentheses appear to be unbalanced.

Comment: Regardless, you can't just add an Interview to a Maybe Int, you'll have to use fmap.

Comment: @overactor autocorrect strikes again

Comment: @JoeSteel If someone's answer doesn't work for you the best thing to do is ask for clarification (with a specific error message, or some expected/actual output) in a comment to the answer. Don't edit your question to ask follow-up questions

Answer (score 1):

One way of structuring `contains :: Eq a => a -> Tree a -> Maybe Integer` is to first *label* each element in your tree with its depth, using something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36480067/1523776), then *fold* the tree to find the element you're looking for, pulling its depth out with it. You can do this without very much code!

Jumping right in where [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36480067/1523776) left off, here's `contains`.

```
contains :: Eq a => a -> Tree a -> Maybe Integer
contains x = fmap fst . find ((== x) . snd) . labelDepths
```

That's the whole function! This is classic functional programming style: rather than hand-crank a bespoke recursive tree traversal function I've structured the code as a *pipeline* of reusable operations. In Haskell pipelines are constructed using the *composition* operator `(.)` and are read from left to right. The result of `labelDepths` is passed to `find ((== x) . snd)`, whose result is then passed to `fmap fst`.

`labelDepths :: Tree a -> Tree (Integer, a)`, which I've explained in detail in [the answer I linked above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36480067/1523776), attaches an `Integer` depth to each element of the input tree.

[`find :: Foldable t => (a -> Bool) -> t a -> Maybe a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:find) is a standard function which extracts the first element of a container (like a tree, or a list) that satisfies a predicate. In this instance, the `Foldable` structure in question is a `Tree`, so `t ~ Tree` and `find :: (a -> Bool) -> Tree a -> Maybe a`. The predicate I've given to `find` is `((== x) . snd)`, which returns `True` if the second element of its input tuple equals `x`: `find ((== x) . snd) :: Tree (Integer, a) -> Maybe (Integer, a)`. `find` works by *folding* the input structure - testing its elements one at a time until it finds one that matches the predicate. The order in which elements are processed is defined by the container's `Foldable` instance, of which more below.

[`fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Functor.html#v:fmap) is another standard function. It applies a *mapping* function uniformly to each element of a container, transforming its elements from type `a` to type `b`. This time the container in question is the return value of `find`, which is a `Maybe`, so `fmap :: (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b`. The mapping function I've supplied is `fst`, which extracts the first element of a tuple: `fmap fst :: Maybe (Integer, a) -> Maybe Integer`.

So putting it all together, you can see that this is a fairly direct implementation of my English description of the process above. First we label every element in the tree with its depth, then we find an element which matches the item we're looking for, then we extract the depth with which the element was previously labelled.

---

I mentioned above that `Tree` is a `Foldable` container. In fact, this isn't the case quite yet - there's no instance of `Foldable` for `Tree`. The easiest way to get a `Foldable` instance for `Tree` is to turn on the `DeriveFoldable` GHC extension and utter the magic words `deriving Foldable`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFoldable #-}
data Tree x = Empty | Node x (Tree x) (Tree x) deriving Foldable
```

This automatically-implemented instance of `Foldable` will perform a preorder traversal, processing the tree in a top-down fashion. (`x` is considered to be "to the left of" `l` and `r` in the expression `Node x l r`.) You can adjust the derived traversal order by adjusting the layout of the `Node` constructor.

That said, I'm guessing that this is an assignment and you're not allowed to modify the definition of `Tree` or apply any language extensions. So you'll need to hand-write your own instance of `Foldable`, following the template at the bottom of this post. Here's an implementation of `foldr` which performs a preorder traversal.

```
instance Foldable Tree where
    foldr f z Empty = z
    foldr f z (Node x l r) = f x (foldr f (foldr f z r) l)
```

The `Node` case is the interesting one. We fold the tree from right to left (since this is a `foldr`) and from bottom to top. First we fold the right subtree, placing `z` at the rightmost leaf. Then we use the aggregated result of the right subtree as the seed for folding the left subtree. Finally we use the result of folding all of the `Node`'s children as the aggregator to apply to `f x`.

---

Hopefully you didn't find this answer too advanced! (Happy to answer any questions you have.) While the other answers do a good job of showcasing how to write recursive tree traversal functions, I really wanted to give you a glimpse of the real power of functional programming. When you think at a higher level - breaking down a problem into its component parts, structuring operations as pipelines, and learning to spot common patterns like *zipping*, *folding* and *mapping* - you can be very productive and solve problems with very little code.

---

---

**An instance of Foldable for a binary tree**

To instantiate `Foldable` you need to provide a definition for at least `foldMap` or `foldr`.

```
data Tree a = Leaf
            | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a)

instance Foldable Tree where
    foldMap f Leaf = mempty
    foldMap f (Node l x r) = foldMap f l `mappend` f x `mappend` foldMap f r

    foldr f acc Leaf = acc
    foldr f acc (Node l x r) = foldr f (f x (foldr f acc r)) l
```

This implementation performs an [in-order traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#In-order) of the tree.

```
ghci> let myTree = Node (Node Leaf 'a' Leaf) 'b' (Node Leaf 'c' Leaf)

--    +--'b'--+
--    |       |
-- +-'a'-+ +-'c'-+
-- |     | |     |
-- *     * *     *

ghci> toList myTree
"abc"
```

The `DeriveFoldable` extension allows GHC to generate `Foldable` instances based on the structure of the type. We can vary the order of the machine-written traversal by adjusting the layout of the `Node` constructor.

```
data Inorder a = ILeaf
               | INode (Inorder a) a (Inorder a)  -- as before
               deriving Foldable

data Preorder a = PrLeaf
                | PrNode a (Preorder a) (Preorder a)
                deriving Foldable

data Postorder a = PoLeaf
                 | PoNode (Postorder a) (Postorder a) a
                 deriving Foldable

-- injections from the earlier Tree type
inorder :: Tree a -> Inorder a
inorder Leaf = ILeaf
inorder (Node l x r) = INode (inorder l) x (inorder r)

preorder :: Tree a -> Preorder a
preorder Leaf = PrLeaf
preorder (Node l x r) = PrNode x (preorder l) (preorder r)

postorder :: Tree a -> Postorder a
postorder Leaf = PoLeaf
postorder (Node l x r) = PoNode (postorder l) (postorder r) x

ghci> toList (inorder myTree)
"abc"
ghci> toList (preorder myTree)
"bac"
ghci> toList (postorder myTree)
"acb"
```

Comment: While newcomers probably find `foldr` a little easier to think about, I think it's much easier to get the definitions right if you define `foldMap` instead. With `foldr`, it's much too easy to get the order all mixed up. The only exceptions are for things that are really list-like, or (like `LogicT`) very closely related to lists.

Comment: @dfeuer Yeah, I find `foldMap` easier to work with too. I went with `foldr` in this instance, at risk of getting things in the wrong order in my code (I _think_ I got it right), because the answer is already pretty dense and I didn't want to digress into an explanation of `Monoid`.

Answer (score 0):

This function doesn't need to be a lambda:

```
contains x t =
```

Adding `x` to the case serves no purpose, since you only match it back to `x`.  You can instead use pattern matching in the function head:

```
contains _ Empty = Nothing
```

The `Node` case has three sub-cases, where the value being searched for is less-than, greater-than, or equal to the value in the `Node`.  If you order them that way, you get a symmetry from the less-than and greater-than tests, and can handle the equal case with an `otherwise`.

When recusring, you are going to get a `Maybe Int`, to which you want to add one.  You can't do that directly because the `Int` is inside the `Maybe`.  Normally, you would lift the addition, but I suspect that this is where the required call to `maybe` should go (however unnatural it may seem):

```
contains x (Node x' l r) | x < x' = maybe Nothing (Just . (+1)) $ contains x l
                         | x > x' = maybe Nothing (Just . (+1)) $ contains x r
                         | otherwise = Just 0
```

Instead of using `maybe`, the `(+1)` could have been lifted into the `Maybe` with `fmap` (or `<$>`):

```
... = fmap (+1) $ contains ...
```

Using `maybe` is unnatural because it has to explicitly pass the `Nothing`, and also re-wrap the `Just`.

Comment: You seem to have missed a (ridiculous, of course) teacher-imposed rule in the question: "I am *not* allowed to use any helper functions".

Comment: @dfeuer, the second part of that very sentence says, "and I am supposed to use the maybe function".  Not sure what other function you're talking about.  The reference to fmap was just to show how to do it more succinctly.  Of course, technically speaking, even `+` and `.` are functions.

Answer (score 0):

> This does not work, since I get a parse error on input `|`

Your previous line misses a closing parenthesis.

> I got a Typ error about `(1+ (contains x l))`, so this probably is not correct.

The idea is totally correct, the issue is that `contains x l` returns a `Maybe Int` instead of an `Int` so you cannot directly add to that. You can only add to the result when it's a `Just`. There's a helper function that does exactly that, do something to `Just`s and keep `Nothing`s: [`fmap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:fmap) (from `Functor`).

```
contains = \x t -> case (x,t) of 
(x,Empty)-> Nothing
(x,tx@(Node x1 l1 r1)) 
    |x==x1 -> Just 0 
    |x>x1  -> fmap (1+) (contains x l)
    |x<x1  -> fmap (1+) (contains x r)
```

Btw, I'd write this as

```
contains x Empty        = Nothing
contains x (Node v l r) = if x == v 
    then Just 0
    else fmap (+1) $ contains x $ if x > v then l else r
```

Comment: Thanks! This is almost correct. You need to add "heap" when the contains functions is called,  so the correct version would be: "contains heap x l" and "contains heap x r" (only figuered it out after finding a working implementation)  However this somehow does not deliver correct answeres for ALL cases.

Comment: The tree's meant to be a min heap, isn't it? Not a binary search tree. The ordering invariant of a min heap is "the current node is smaller than either of its children", not "the left subtree contains elements smaller than the current node, and the right subtree contains elements greater than the current node". Picking a child by comparing `x` with `x1` isn't right.

Comment: @JoeSteel The heap is the tree, right? It's the second parameter (`t`). The `contains` function should not take three parameters.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Drat, I skipped that part of the question and just fixed the obvious problem for a `contains` function in an ordered tree. Yes, the algorithm is plain wrong for a Heap.